# Authentication failed django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am learning Django, i was creating rest Api for login and registration api it was working but all of sudden Login api is not working

`authenticate(username=username, password=password)`

is always returning none while registration api work properly. below is code for login

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def login(requset):
    """
    This api for user login
    ---
    parameters:
    - name: username
      description: username for login
      required: true
      type: string
      paramType: form
    - name: password
      required: true
      type: string
      paramType: form
    consumes:
        - application/json
        - application/xml
    produces:
        - application/json
        - application/xml
    """
    username = requset.data.get('username')
    print(username)
    password = requset.data.get('password')
    print(password)
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        response_data = {}
        response_data['result'] = 'success'
        response_data['message'] = 'Login successful'
        # response_data['auth_token'] = auth_token

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),
                            content_type="application/json")
    else:
        response_data = {}
        response_data['result'] = 'error'
        response_data['message'] = 'Login Unsuccessful'
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data),
                                     content_type="application/json")
```

This is code for registration

```
class Register(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """
    Your docs
    ---
    type:
      username:
        required: true
        type: string
      password:
        required: true
        type: url
      email:
        required: true
        type: string

    serializer: .serializers.UserSerializer
    omit_serializer: false

    parameters_strategy: merge
    omit_parameters:
        - path
    parameters:
        - name: username
          description: Username for registration purpose
          required: true
          type: string
          paramType: form
        - name: password
          description: * password for registration purpose
          required: true
          type: string
          paramType: form
        - name: email
          description: * email for registration purpose
          required: true
          type: string
          paramType: form

    responseMessages:
        - code: 401
          message: Not authenticated

    consumes:
        - application/json
        - application/xml
    produces:
        - application/json
        - application/xml
    """

    #first define query set
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    #define model
    model = User
    #define serializer
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Code for userserializer

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','username','email','password','is_active')
```

i always get below response

```
{
  "message": "Login Unsuccessful",
  "result": "error"
}
```

While previously it was coming proper. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You are using serializer to register, it will not hash the password(will be saved as plain text) and authenticate will hash the password and then check.

Comment: So, can you confirm that your registration is the problem? After a registration, can you find the new User on the admin pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, if you just set password in a user serializer, your password will be saved in plaintext where Django expects a hash. So you need to do something like this

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','username','email','password','is_active')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = super().create(validated_data)
        if 'password' in validated_data:
            user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
            user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: Thanks @Mad Wombat